# 3 coloring a necklace

Tags: combinatorics

How many different $n$-bead necklaces cyclically distinct can be made from three colors of beads when:

(a) $n = 7$

(b) $n = 9$

Workings:

(a) The rotations are $0^o, \frac{360}{7}^o, \frac{720}{7}^o, \frac{1080}{7}^o, \frac{1440}{7}^o, \frac{1800}{7}^o, \frac{2160}{7}^o$

The $0^o$ rotation consists of $7$ $1$-cycles.

The $\frac{360}{7}^o$ is the cyclic permutation $(abcdefg)$

The $\frac{720}{7}^o$ is the cycle decomposition $(acegbdf)$

The $\frac{1080}{7}^o$ is the cycle decomposition $(adgcfbe)$

The $\frac{1440}{7}^o$ is the cycle decomposition $(aebfcgd)$

The $\frac{1800}{7}^o$ is the cycle decomposition $(afdbgec)$

The $\frac{2160}{7}^o$ is the cycle decomposition $(agfedcb)$

The cycle structure representations are then

$0^o x_1^7$

And $x_7$ for the rest of the terms

Collecting terms gives.

$P_G = \frac{1}{7}(x_1^7 + 6x_7)$

So the number of different $m$-colored necklace of secen beads is

$\frac{1}{7}(m^7 + 6m)$

For $m = 3$:

$\frac{1}{7}(3^7 + 6(3)) = 315$

(b) The rotations are $0^o, 40^o, 80^o, 120^o, 160^o, 200^o, 240^o, 280^o, 320^o$

The $0^o$ rotation consists of $9$ $1$-cycles

The $40^o$ is the cycle decomposition $(abcdefghi)$

The $80^o$ is the cycle decomposition $(acegibdfh)$

The $120^o$ is the cycle decomposition $(adg)(beh)(cfi)$

The $160^o$ is the cycle decomposition $(aeidhcgbf)$

The $200^o$ is the cycle decomposition $(afbgchdie)$

The $240^o$ is the cycle decomposition $(agd)(bhe)(cif)$

The $280^o$ is the cycle decomposition $(ahfdbigec)$

The $320^o$ is the cycle decomposition $(aihgfedbc)$

The cycle structure representations are then

$0^o x_1^9$

For $40^o, 80^o, 160^0, 200^o, 280^0, 320^0 x_9$

For $120^o, 240^0 x_3^3$

This gives

$P_G = \frac{1}{9}(x_1^9 + 6x_9 + 2x_3^3)$

So the number of $m$-colored necklaces is

$\frac{1}{9}(m^9 + 6m + 2m^3)$

For $m = 3$:

$\frac{1}{9}((3)^9 + 6(3) + 3(3)^3) = 2198$

I'm wondering if I did this right. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: so we are making 7 and 9 distinct beaded distinct necklaces?

Comment: Yes I believe so

Comment: won't you use factorial?anyways, i can't seem t understand your answer.

Comment: i would do $7!/(7*2)=360$ and $9!/(9*2)=20160$

Comment: I based it off from my textbook for 8 beads. The rotations would be $0^o, 45^o, 135^o, 180^o, 225^o, 270^o$ and $315^o$ The $0^o$ rotation gives $8$ $1$-cycles. The $45^o$ gives cycle decomposition $(abcdefgh)$. The $90^o$ rotation had cycle decompsition $(aceg)(bdfh)$. The $135^o$ rotation gives $9adgehcf)$. The $180^o$ gives $(ae)(bf)(cg)(dh)$. The $220^o, 270^o, 315^o$ are the reverse of $135^o, 90, 45$ respectively. The cycle structure representations would then be for $0^o x_1^8, 45^o x_8, 90^o x_4^2, 135^o x_8$ and $180^o$, $x_2^4$

Comment: Collecting terms gives $P_G = \frac{1}{8}(x_1^8 + 4x_8 +2x_4^3 + x_2^4)$ So the number of different $m$-colored necklaces is $\frac{1}{8}(m^8+4m+2m^2+m^4)$ For $m = 3$: $\frac{1}{8}(3^8+4 \times 3 + 2 \times 3^2 + 3^4) = 834$

Comment: You made a computational error at the end of the second problem: $$\frac19(m^9+6m+2m^3)=\frac19(3^9+6\cdot3+\underline{2}\cdot3^3)=2195\;.$$ Otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for the help.

Comment: @CoolNewFriends: You're welcome.